# google home actions catch all query with Actions SDK

Tags: actions-on-google

Our company already has as a conversational service for intent matching and entity parsing.  Let's call this service "Charlie".

If we were to integrate Google Home with our service, would we have to repeat all of our existing queries in the action package or is there way to have a catch-all query so when we say to "talk to Charlie", Google Home forwards future utterances to our Charlie service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Actions SDK which gives you access to the raw user query and then can do your own NLU and generate the expected JSON response to keep the conversation going.

If you use the `Node.js` client library then you can use the `assistant.getRawInput()` method.

See the sample app for complete logic:  [Github - actionssdk-say-number-nodejs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-say-number-nodejs)

Comment: will speech to recognition accuracy be affected by using this approach?

Comment: Speech recognition is the same, but your NLU needs to make sense of what the user meant.